# How to keep `click` event on sortable elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

`.itemp` are children inside `.pwrap`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.itemp', function() {
console.log('323');
});
```

the above works but:

```
$('.pwrap').sortable({
axis: "y",
connectWith: ".pwrap",
tolerance: 'pointer',
update: function(event, ui) {
    $('#btnsave').addClass('btnred');
}
});
```

with the above code `click` event doesn't work.

How to keep `click` event on sortable elements?

Comment: as you can see it works. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6ny1rqw/) Could you clarify the problem? Thanks

Comment: @gaetanoM, it doesn't work. Alert is there only after click. I need it after click and after sorting, because element IS CLICKED before sorting.

Comment: If you want the alert after the sorting, go ahead and put the console.log('323') line into the update method.

Comment: @AnthonyCollins, I simplified my `click` event. In fact it is much more complex. This is the reason I want to keep them separetely.

Answer (score 0):

try adding disableSelection() and delegate click event

```
$('.pwrap').sortable({
    axis: "y",
    connectWith: ".pwrap",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $('#btnsave').addClass('btnred');
    }
    }).disableSelection().on("click", ".itemp", function() {
        console.log('323');
    });
```

if you wand the click on a separate event use

add     `$('.pwrap').on('sortupdate',function() {alert('323')});`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.itemp', function() {
  alert('323');
});

$('.pwrap').sortable({
  axis: "y",
  connectWith: ".pwrap",
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    $('#btnsave').addClass('btnred');
  }
});
$('.pwrap').on('sortupdate',function() {alert('323')});
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="sortable" class="pwrap">
    <li class="ui-state-default itemp"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default itemp"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default itemp"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default itemp"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default itemp"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default itemp"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default itemp"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hmm... I need the `click` as separate event, because of `click` without `drag`.

Comment: The use of `$('.pwrap').on('sortupdate',function() {alert('323')});` is probably the best way to go here (like @Ram Segev pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

The click events associated with the `sortable()` element are going to take precedence over the other one that you defined.

I suggest that you put your `console.log()` logic in a "start" method for the `sortable()`. Something along the lines of this should work:

```
$('.pwrap').sortable({
    axis: "y",
    connectWith: ".pwrap",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('323');
        // anything else you want to do...
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $('#btnsave').addClass('btnred');
    }
});
```

Let me know if this works. If it does, please mark this answer appropriately.

Comment: you say - `The click events associated with the .sortable() element are going to take precedence...` but `click` associated with the `sortable` doesn't exist in my code.

Comment: What I mean is that jQuery's source code creates click events on top of yours that override your .itemp click events.

Comment: could you give me the source for your assumption? I would be surprised if this is true. Why would jquery override my existing code ?